# Scipy Root Finding non square matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Why is it not possible to insert a non square matrix in one scipy optimizing function?
(I mean the function F has more rows than variables)

```
def F(x):
    L = numpy.zeros(13)
    L[0] = x[0]*x[0] - x[0]
    L[1] = x[1]*x[1] - x[1]
    L[2] = x[2]*x[2] - x[2]
    L[3] = x[3]*x[3] - x[3]
    L[4] = x[4]*x[4] - x[4]
    L[5] = x[5]*x[5] - x[5]
    L[6] = x[6]*x[6] - x[6]
    L[7] = x[7]*x[7] - x[7]

    L[8] = x[0]+x[1]+x[2]-2
    L[9] = x[5]+x[6]-x[7]-2
    L[10] = 3*x[0]+x[1]+x[2]-1
    L[11] = x[0]+x[4]+x[3]-2
    L[12] = x[3]-2*x[5]+x[7]-2
    return L

x = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]


print x
print F(x)
y = scipy.optimize.root(F, x)
```

What can i use then instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `optimize.root` requires F to take an array of shape (N,) and return
an array of shape (N,).

One exception to that is when `method='lm'` is used.  [The docs say](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html),

> Method lm solves the system of nonlinear equations in a least squares sense
>   using a modification of the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm as implemented in
>   MINPACK [R110].

Running

```
sol = optimize.root(F, x, method='lm')
print(sol.x)
print(sol.fun))
```

yields

```
[-0.25534031  1.00426132  1.00426132  1.26246697  0.99641747 -0.1852661
  1.32671248 -0.14183467]
[ 0.32053899  0.00427948  0.00427948  0.33135589 -0.00356969  0.21958963
  0.43345353  0.16195174 -0.24681766 -0.71671895  0.24250171  0.00354414
 -0.50883549]
```

So although a "solution" was found, it is not a root of `F`.
Why is that? With `method='lm'`, `optimize.root` is returning a 
solution which *minimizes* `|F|^2`. It's the same location as you would find using `optimize.minimize`:

```
def Fnorm(x):
    return (F(x)**2).sum()

res = optimize.minimize(Fnorm, x)

print(res['x'])
# array([-0.25534014,  1.00426118,  1.00426118,  1.26246497,  0.99641833,
#        -0.1852652 ,  1.32672144, -0.14182902])

print(res['fun'])
# 1.3672594815275587
```